# Dynamically switching pin out

Tags: wires, software

I have a connector with 10 pins, and a bus which uses 2 of the 10 pins.

What I need to do is, in software, attach my arduino to 2 of the 10 pins. I cannot wire it directly as the 2 pins required may be in a different position in different environments.

What are my options?

**EDIT:** Just some background. I have to connect to an OBD II port of a vehicle and cannot to the CAN bus. On some vehicles is may not be on the standard pins in the OBD connector, so I would like to be able to programatically switch the pins being used, in software.

Comment: Could you connect all 10 pins to the Arduino and select which of them to use in the Arduino software?

Comment: No, mainly due to the bus requirements - think SPI, only works on certain Arduino pins.

Comment: If there are other requirements not stated, it would be useful to edit them into the question. I can think of a few ways of doing this. Whether any of them will be suitable depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Fair point. I tried to be as generic as possible to keep it simple, but I have added background in case it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need two SP10T switches, where you can programmatically decide which of the SPI pins will be sent to which of the 10 outputs which are connected to the 10 pin bus.